# How is it that the await word doesn't actually await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, google-calendar-api

I wrote this code to query the google calendar API and return result.

For simplification, I inserted the variable x to the function. From my intuition, x should be printed as 1, but it always gets printed as 1.

The original problem is that the result from the calendar always becomes undefined although if I print it inside the asynchronous call, it gets printed correctly.

What have I done wrong, and how to fix it please?

```js
async askCal() {
        let x = 0;
        await this.calendar.freebusy.query(this.auth, (err, response) => {
            x = 1;
            if (err) { console.log('error: ' + err) }
        })
        console.log({ x })
    }
```

Comment: Because you passed a callback function. Either use `await` _or_ a callback function _or_ `.then()`, not a mix of two or more. `const response = await this.calendar.freebusy.query(this.auth);`

Comment: `From my intuition, x should be printed as 1, but it always gets printed as 1.` doesn't make sense.

Comment: `await` doesn't magically wait for some arbitrary callback, it waits for the promise that is its operand. Does `this.calendar.freebusy.query()` return a promise?

Comment: If `x` is logged as `0` (which I guess you meant to write) it means that the callback you pass as 2nd argument is not executed. Which makes sense if the query method returns a Promise that'll resolve to the result (because in that case there is no 2nd parameter)

Answer (score 2):

you mix between callback and await/async,

```
     async askCal() {
            try{
             let x = 0;    
             const response = await this.calendar.freebusy.query(this.auth);
             x = 1;           
             console.log({ x });
          }catch(e){console.error(e.message);}
         
        }
```